# How to wait for a process session to finish

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wait

I have the following code which I use to run multiple processes in background, one after the other (which I got from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204480/run-multiple-commands-and-kill-them-as-one-in-bash)):

```
setsid sh -c '( command1 > command1.out ; wait \
& command2 > command2.out )' &
pgid=$!
echo "Background tasks are running in process group $pgid, kill with kill -TERM -$pgid"
```

I would like to know if it's possible for another process to use the resulting `$pgid` and wait before starting? When I try using

```
wait $pgid
```

I get `pid xxxx is not a child of this shell`

Could anyone be generous to help me out? :)

Comment: No, it's not directly possible to wait for an arbitrary process or group. You have to busy-loop *and* handle/avoid PID reuse somehow (either by checking the timestamp or keeping a /proc fd open).

Comment: If you're doing many process-order dependencies, perhaps you really should be writing an init script. Or systemd, since that's the main toy these days, and has per-user instances.